# Generating $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

I have this question which doesn't seem too difficult and I would like to know if there is an elementary way to deal with it.

I consider a closed subgroup $G$ of $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ which contains infinitely many copies of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ which are actual stabilizers of $2$-planes. Let's call the elements of this family the $G_i$'s and the stabilized $2$-planes $P_i$.

I aslo suppose that the family of the $P_i$'s is irreducible in the sense that there is no non-trivial decomposition $\mathbb{R}^n = E \oplus F$ such that for all $i$, either $P_i \subset E$ or $P_i \subset F$.

My question is: does $G =  \mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ ?

Comment: This is already false when n=3, just use the subgroups fixing a common line.